# Installing Racket Packages without installing Dr Racket

Tags: package, racket, package-managers

I am running a minimal install of Racket and wish to install the [sql](http://docs.racket-lang.org/sql@sql/index.html) package. If I try the command:

```
raco pkg install sql
```

I am prompted to install `racket-doc`, which has a dependency on `drracket`. I would rather not install the whole IDE, as I have space constraints on my application.

I have also tried the `--no-docs` flag, which did not have an effect on `raco`'s behavior as far as I can tell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--no-docs` means it will not setup documentation, but it is still a dependency!

Note however that `sql`'s [`info.rkt`](https://github.com/rmculpepper/sql/blob/master/info.rkt) indicates `racket-doc` as a `built-deps`. That means if you install a [binary package](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/strip.html#%28tech._binary._package%29) from the [built-package catalog](https://pkg-build.racket-lang.org/about.html), `racket-doc` will no longer be a dependency.

## For Racket 7.6 (current version as of writing) and before:

(Note: this solution is due to Jack Firth)

As a first step, we need to add the built-package catalog to the list of catalogs that `raco pkg` will use by default. This could be done by:

```
$ raco pkg config --set catalogs \
    "https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/7.6/catalog/" \
    "https://pkg-build.racket-lang.org/server/built/catalog/" \
    "https://pkgs.racket-lang.org" \
    "https://planet-compats.racket-lang.org"
```

(assuming you are using Racket 7.6)

Then, install binary `sql`:

```
$ raco pkg install --binary sql
```

## For Racket with version after 7.6

Simply run:

```
$ raco pkg install \
    --catalog "https://pkgs.racket-lang.org" \ 
    --catalog "https://pkg-build.racket-lang.org/server/built/catalog/" \
    --binary sql
```